# How to get User queryset from his Profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Good afternoon. I am creating a referral system and at the last stage a question appeared. I need to get request.User and inviting.User querysets for Friends.create.objects(inviting=current_user, invited=inviting_query.user)

How i get they?

My models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invite_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)
    was_invited = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Friends(models.Model):
    inviting = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invited')
    # кого пригласили
    invited = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invinting')
    # кто пригласил
```

Post function:

```
    def post(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
        invite_code = request.POST['invite_code']

        invited_user = Profile.objects.filter(invite_code=invite_code)
        current_user = request.user

        Friends.objects.create(inviting=current_user, invited=invited_user)

        return render(request, 'api_auth_user/user-profile.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `user` of the `Profile`, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def post(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    invite_code = request.POST['invite_code']

    invited_user_id = get_object_or_404(Profile, invite_code=invite_code)
    current_user = request.user

    Friends.objects.create(
        inviting=request.user, invited_id=invited_user_id.user_id
    )

    return render(request, 'api_auth_user/user-profile.html')
```

It looks however quite strange that a `Profile` has an invite code, that would mean that each user has a single invite code that can be used by everyone?

Comment: Each user who has been authorized at least once has a code, you can be invited only once, but you can invite many. This is a job test. Your method is not quite correct. My models do not have such attributes. But you helped me, thank you)
        Friends.objects.create(
            inviting=invited_user_id.user, invited=request.user
        )

Comment: @dkarmm: what attributes? For each `ForeignKey` named `foo`, you also have a `foo_id` that stores the token it references, since your `Profile` has a `user` field, you thus can work with `user_id`, and since your `Friends` has an `invited`, field, it has an `invited_id`.

Comment: @dkarmm: using `.user` will work, but is a bad idea from a performance perspective, since it will make an additional query. This is exactly what I wanted to avoid: making one extra query on two queries, is an increase of 50%...

Comment: Yes, now I see that I have an extra request. I did not know about the existence of these attributes. But if you use your code, then an error is thrown: NameError at /auth/profile/
name 'invited_profile' is not defined

Comment: @dkarmm: yes, I made a typo :)